# How to parse response of Mapbox reverse geocoding in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using Mapbox in my android **Kotlin** application, I perform a reverse geocoding and expecting to get the full address of the place :

**Here is my code:**

```
val geoCoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
  .accessToken(accessToken)
  .country("eg")
  .query(Point.fromLngLat(long, lat))
  .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_PLACE)
  .build()
println(geoCoding)
```

**The response I got from the line `println(geoCoding)` is:**

```
Geooding{query=31.23944,30.05611, mode=mapbox.places, accessToken="My access token are shown here" , baseUrl=https://api.mapbox.com, country=eg, proximity=null, geocodingTypes=place, autocomplete=null, bbox=null, limit=null, languages=null, reverseMode=null, fuzzyMatch=null, clientAppName=null
```

So , as you see there is no info shown at all , despite that all the info are being shown if I performed the query using a normal api URL in my chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's not visible from the code... Are you sure you are calling

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback

    geoCoding.enqueueCall(object : Callback<GeocodingResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("FAILURE", t.toString())
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>, response: retrofit2.Response<GeocodingResponse>) {
            Log.d("SUCCESS", response.body().toString())
        }
    })
```

after the `.build()`?

Comment: Using this line of code ` val response:GeocodingResponse =geoCoding.executeCall().body()!!` then tryint to print `response` , causes `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

Comment: that is pure Java, aslo after converting to kotlin , a lot of methods are not callable ! this the example in the official documentation which is not working at all, any help on how to achieve this success in kotlin?

Comment: please add the import `import retrofit2.Call, 
import retrofit2.Callback` as it is where my problem was. I was importing the Wrong Callback